# Display row number without moving column

Tags: vba, row, togglebutton, rostering

I have built a 12 month roster in which I have the 365 days across 365 columns and my 120 employees listed down in each row, down to row 120.

I am looking for some VBA code that will allow me to (for example) to display row 120 whilst keeping the active column in display.

I am currently using the below simple code which does highlight the row but resets the column set to show Column A. I am using toggle buttons to initiate the macros.

```
Sub ToggleButton3_Click()
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "70").Activate
End Sub
```

Any tips, solutions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a procedure like this:

```
Public Sub MoveToRow()
    ActiveSheet.Cells(70, ActiveCell.Column).Activate
End Sub
```

And associate it to a keyboard shortcut (i.e. CTRL + J). Open the **Macro Dialog** -> Select `ThisWorkBook.MoveToRow()` -> Click the "**Options**" Button -> **Assign the shortcut**. It works :)

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked perfectly. Much appreciated.  :)

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad it worked. Could you please accept the answer? Thank you and good bye!